# How do I add HTML in Excel, when I copy and paste into a HTML document it adds an extra quote sign ""

Tags: html, excel, excel-formula

So I have a complex excel sheet full of product data and I am using formulas and VBA to quicken the sorting process. However, I am trying to use HTML code in the cells and when I copy the Concatenate it will add an extra "" with HTML tags. for example:

```
<h3 class=""showOnMobile"">Swipe right or rotate your device to see full table</h3>
<div class=""tablewrapper"">
```

**This is my concatenation in excel**

```
=CONCATENATE(E3,F3,R3)
```

Basically, each of the cells consists of the code you see below.
Cell R3 basically has singular quatation marks ""

```
<h3 class="showOnMobile">Swipe right or rotate your device to see full table</h3>
<div class="tablewrapper">
```

**This is the code that displays in my HTML editor after I copy and paste the concatenation**

```
<p>Work Floor Ramp</p>
<ul>
<li> Heavy-duty polyethylene ramp compatible with DRP20.</li>
<li> Fitted with locating pins which slot into DRP20 work floor for added stability when manoeuvring drum.</li>
<li> Manufactured with non slip resistant texture.</li>
<li> Features user friendly gradient for easy loading.</li>
</ul>
<h3 class=""showOnMobile"">Swipe right or rotate your device to see full table</h3>
<div class=""tablewrapper"">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Model No:</th>
<td>12345</td>
</tr><tr>
<th>Dimensions (W x D x H):</th>
<td>810 x 1290 x 180mm</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is in cells `E3`, `F3`, and `R3`? Please edit question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Linebreaks.

If you just copy cell R3 and paste it into Notepad, you'll see that it displays as

```
"<h3 class=""showOnMobile"">Swipe right or rotate your device to see full table</h3><div class=""tablewrapper"">"
```

instead of

```
<h3 class="showOnMobile">Swipe right or rotate your device to see full table</h3>
<div class="tablewrapper">
```

Your "best" solution would probably be to make sure that each line of HTML is a new cell/row in Excel